# Remove Email Footer and signs using java

Tags: java, email, email-parsing

Hi Can someone tell how to remove the footer from the mail.
I just need to store the body of the email and remove the other things be it a disclaimer or a footer.

Answer (score 0):

There is meant to be a standard marker for email footers - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_block#Standard_delimiter

Which is:

`--`

You can use a regex to look for that, e.g.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^-- $", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(emailBodyText);
    if (m.find()) {
        emailBodyText = emailBodyText.substring(0, m.start());
    }
```

Sadly it is not widely used these days. For example, Gmail does not apply it.

For a gmail message - You can look for data-smartmail="gmail_signature" in the email's html.

You might have to implement custom clean-up code for each major email system.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a regular expression.

Let's say the email looks like

```
String emailContents = 
    "AAA this is the email header BBB\n" +
    "This is the body\n" +
    "CCC this is the email footer DDD";
```

You could do something like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("AAA.*BBB(.*)CCC.*DDD");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(emailContents);
if (!matcher.matches()) throw new Exception("Invalid email");
String emailBody = matcher.group(1);
System.out.println(emailBody); // prints 'This is the body'
```

Note that `.*` matches any character multiple times and `(` and `)` represent a [group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html). Full regex syntax [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)